# split by dot for a column from pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with a ***name*** column as below

```
name
Dr. Maso Guilani
Paul Dupey
Mrs. Sarah Kant
Cathay Pane
Canine Paul
```

I want  to remove strings like "Dr. ,  Mrs." from that "name" column

I tried as below.

```
df['name']=df.name.replace({"Mrs.": ""},regex=True).replace({"Dr.": ""},regex=True)
```

But I want to generalize this as I am not sure how many prefixes like "Dr. ,  Mrs." are
available in the huge dataset. Basically I want to remove all the prefix with dots. Thanks.

Expected output:

```
name
Maso Guilani
Paul Dupey
Sarah Kant
Cathay Pane
Canine Paul
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following. Using [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) function of Pandas here. Simple explanation of regex would be: replacing everything from starting of value(with a lazy match) till first dot followed by 1 or more spaces with NULL in name column.

```
df['name'].str.replace(r'^.*?\.\s+','')
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Maso Guilani
Paul Dupey
Sarah Kant
Cathay Pane
Canine Paul
```

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing this:

Via `split()` and `apply()` method:

```
df['name']=df['name'].str.split('.',1).apply(lambda x:x[1] if len(x)>1 else x[0])
```

Output of `df`:

```
0     Maso Guilani
1       Paul Dupey
2       Sarah Kant
3      Cathay Pane
4      Canine Paul
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO Anurag's is the right approach, Pandastically speaking. But if, like me, you prefer slick over readable, you can slicken it up slightly:

```py
    df['name'] = df['name'].str.split('.',1).str[-1]
```

This is equivalent, and it should work for strings without any periods or even for empty strings, as long as there aren't extra periods that occur before title periods.